# Javascript: store last generated random numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Making a project which involves generating random numbers, which is easy enough with Math.random(). A new number will be generated every n seconds, and i want to be able to display the 5 most recent numbers.

The best I could come up with is creating an array with all the generated numbers, pushing new ones, and then getting the 5 most recent indexes.

Is there a better way to only store only the 5 most recent, as there will be thousands of these numbers being generated?

Comment: why not push and shift at the same time

Comment: what is the range of number you want to display ?

Comment: Why am i asking is because if you want to show 2 or 3 digit number then no need to have any array you can try (Math.random() * Math.random()) = some random long number like 0.1612435949049499. You can show digits out of this string.

Comment: @RanjeetGautam numbers will be between 0-100 (not inclusive) to 2 d.p. Have worked out how to generate those I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The best I could come up with is creating an array with all the
>   generated numbers, pushing new ones, and then getting the 5 most
>   recent indexes.

Rather than just pushing, do [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and push

```
var randomArr = [];
function addRandom()
{
   //var newNum = randomNumber();

   if ( randomArr.length >= 5 )
   {
       randomArr.shift();
   }       
   randomArr.push( newNum );  
}
```

Now you don't need to do a splice, just take the `randomArr` array as is.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var array = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
function addToArray() {
  array.push(Math.random());
  array.shift();
}
function getLast5() {
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic Maybe like below just do it with random numbers I am showing you with fixed numbers to make it more clear what is happening behind the scene

```
var randomNumbers= [];
randomNumbers.push(2);         // randomNumbers is now [2]
randomNumbers.push(5);         // randomNumbers is now [2, 5]
randomNumbers.push(7);         // randomNumbers is now [2, 5, 7]
randomNumbers.push(9);         // randomNumbers is now [2, 5, 7, 9]
randomNumbers.push(1);         // randomNumbers is now [2, 5, 7, 9, 1]

randomNumbers.shift(); // randomNumbers is now [5, 7, 9, 1]

randomNumbers.push(10);         // randomNumbers is now [5, 7, 9, 1, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

With ECMAScript2016, you can do:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var newNumber = 4;
arr = [ ...arr.slice(1), newNumber ];
console.log(arr);
```